# MauiImage resource accessible as stream in Android

Tags: android, maui

I'm migrating an app from Xamarin.Forms to MAUI. Everything is going surprisingly smoothly so far!

There are a small number of images added as SVG resources to the app that are displaying at fixed locations in the app (ie defined in the XAML). The app generates views in a SkiaSharp Canvas from large amounts of downloaded content and that content includes images downloaded from the cloud which are rendering fine (as SKBitmap from the file stream).

A few of the image references in the downloaded content are for the SVG resources that are being included in the app. I have determined a way to get the stream for the resource images in iOS but I cannot find any way to do this in Android.

In iOS:

```
var imageStream = await FileSystem.OpenAppPackageFileAsync(resourceName + ".png");
```

This throws a 'FileNotFoundException' when running on Android...

What I've found DOES work in Android:

```
#if ANDROID
   // The only reference I can find that actually loads the image in any way
   var drawable = MainApplication.Current.GetDrawable(resourceId);
   height = drawable?.IntrinsicHeight ?? 0;
   width = drawable?.IntrinsicWidth ?? 0;
#endif
```

However the Drawable returned (native Android type) has no way that I can find of converting into a Stream and I can't find any way in SkiaSharp libraries to just dump the Drawable onto the SKCanvas?

Diving into the packages generated I can see that the iOS IPA package has the SVGs saved as PNGs in the root of the package (likely why I can load them using OpenAppPackageFileAsync) while in the Android APK the images are split out into /res/drawable-XXXXXXX folders (where XXXXXXX is hdpi / ldrti / xhdpi / etc for the different device resolutions).

Comment: While writing this question I realised I hadn't tried putting in one of the /res/drawable-XXXXXXX folders when using OpenAppPackageFileAsync. Unfortunately this didn't change the outcome on Android (still FileNotFoundException)

Comment: Did you update SkiaSharp NuGet packages after migrating to MAUI?

Comment: Do you have a working SvgView?

Comment: Is the `BuildAction` of the svg resource "`MauiAsset`"? and/or put it in folder `Resources/Raw`? From [File system helpers / Platform differences / FileSystem.OpenAppPackageFileAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/storage/file-system-helpers#platform-differences): *".NET MAUI projects will process any file in the Resources\Raw folder as a MauiAsset."*

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Using as MauiImage because they need to be handled in that way. Don't really want to pad out the package with two copies of all the images if I can help it. Thought that being able to easily access the streams on iOS would mean some similar mechanism for Android but maybe not...

Comment: @DongzhiWang-MSFT SkiaSharp is the MAUI package. The problem is I can't figure out how to get the MauiImage assigned svgs (converted to pngs by build process) to render in the canvas

Comment: @FreakyAli I'm not trying to render SVGs in this instance. I have a whole other mechanism for doing that, however the MAUI components I want to be imported for general use in the app but also accessible.

Comment: You can try adding any file into the Assets folder in the Android project and mark the Build Action as AndroidAsset to use it with OpenAppPackageFileAsync.